# Dart generic constraints to several types and set default value

Tags: generics, dart, default, extend

I want to make some extension classes for RxDart classes, for convenience. But I couldn't find a way to do some basic thing with generics, e.g. I need to restrict generic type to a couple of types. Here's how I would implement it in C#

```
MyGenericType<T> where T : bool, int { ... }
```

thus restricting T to just bool and int types. How would I do the same in dart?
The docs only show examples with a single type restriction like this:

```
class MyGeneric<T extends SomeClass> ...
```

I tried using comma as well, but it does another thing, it requires my generic type to extend both of them, which is not what I need. Is it possible at all?

And another related question: I also need to set default values for those generics. Again, the C# equivalent would be

```
T value = default(T);
```

Is there anything like this in dart?

Answer (score 1):

No, and no.

Dart does not have multiple constraints or union types, so you can't have a type variable containing either `bool` or `int`, nor a normal variable allowing values of only those types.

Dart types also do not have any way to define default value.
Use nullable types and `null` as the default value instead. All types in Dart are object types and can be made nullable by adding `?`.