# Is there a default keyword in Dart?

Tags: c#, dart

I am just wondering if there is a default keyword to initialize value to default in dart?

In c# we can do this.

```
var someType = default(SomeType); // null
var intVar = default(int); // 0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152217/dart-generic-constraints-to-several-types-and-set-default-value

Comment: I see, so there's no feature like that for now, thank you.